# Mysqlでafter insert update triggerの設定方法につきまして。

Tags: mysql

お世話になります。どうかご指導、アドバイス等頂けませんでしょうか。

以下の様な、tbl_productsにデータがinsertされた直後に起動させるトリガーをmysqlで作成しましたが、データを新規にtbl_productsにinsertしても起動いたしません。

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `Percent` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_products`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE
  tbl_products t1,
  ( SELECT id, (rate * number) AS prt
    FROM tbl_products GROUP BY id
  ) t2
SET
  t1.option = t2.prt
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.id
END
```

代わりに、上記のBEGIN～ENDの中にある記述をphpMyAdminのSQLから実行すると期待通りの結果になります。（計算結果prtがtbl_productsのカラムoptionに代入されます）

ですので、mysql上でのトリガーの作成方法に問題があるのではないかと考えておりますが、なぜデータをtbl_productsにinsertしてもトリガーを起動させないかご指導頂けませんでしょうか。

~~~~~～～～～～～～～～～～～～～～～
別テーブルを使用しての記述

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Percent` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_products`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE
  tbl_product_rate t1,
  ( SELECT tbl_products.id, (rate * number) AS prt
    FROM tbl_products left join tbl_products_rate on tbl_products.id =   tbl_products_rate.id GROUP BY id
  ) t2
SET
  t1.option = t2.prt
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.id
END
```

Comment: Tbl_productsとtbl_products は別テーブルということでいいですか？

Comment: keitaro_so様、申し訳ございません。同じテーブルです。

Answer (score 1):

MySQLトリガーはそのトリガーが設定されているテーブルの自体の改変は認めていません。
再帰的な呼び出しになる可能性があるからですかね？

「ストアドファンクションまたはトリガーは、そのストアドファンクションまたはトリガーを呼び出したステートメントによって (読み取りまたは書き込みに) すでに使用されているテーブルを変更できません。」
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/stored-program-restrictions.html

--
追記
解決方法としては
・アプリケーションで実装する。
・別テーブルに書き出してSELECTする場合は別テーブルをJOINする
・INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE用のテーブルを作り、トリガーを利用して本テーブルに同じようにINSERT,UPDATE,DELETEを実施しさらにやりたいトリガーを実施する
などいくつか方法があると思います。

Comment: keitaro_so様、ご指導頂きまして感謝いたします。ということは、上記の目的を達成したい場合はどうすればよろしいのでしょうか。違うテーブルに代入するトリガーを作りさえすれば解決する問題でしょうか。あるいはそれでも無理なのでしょうか。他のトリガーで、before update insertというケースは同じテーブルでも機能しておりますが、上記の記述は同じテーブルなので、一見して機能しないとすぐお分かりになりましたでしょうか?(保存する時点でエラーがでないので同じテーブルでも問題ないと考えておりました。）

Comment: 上記を達成したい場合は。回答に追記しておきました。before update でも同じです。MySQLのトリガーではよくハマるのでひと目でわかりました。保存する時点ではエラーは出ず、実行時エラーになります。「in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.」こんな感じで出ているはずです。

Comment: keitaro_so様、確認ですが、前回の記述でアプリからinsertした時点でログファイルに頂いたエラーは全く表示されておりません。　＊＊ですので、同じテーブルと判別する以前に何らかの理由にてトリガーが全く起動されていない様な感じが致します＊＊　。その上で、以下の様に代入するテーブルを他テーブルに変更致しましたが、前回と同様、データinsert時点でログファイルには何も表示されず、そして結果を伴いません（データを代入しません、SQLから手動で実行すると代入致します。）変更いたしました記述を最初の質問箇所に補足で追加いたします。どこに問題があるかご指摘いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 上述の記述であれば、tbl_productsにinsertする時点でどのカラムにデータを入れるかという記述がかけているため、トリガーが動作しなかったのではないかと思い、 IF  xxxx <> xxxxx THEN という様な設定をすることによりトリガーを検知、それ以降の記述を実行しているようでございます。大変おさがわせ致しました。

Answer (score 1):

なぜトリガーでは動かないのかは、@keitaro_soさんの回答の通りだと思います。
対応策として、**MySQLのバージョンが5.7.6以降であれば**、generated columnが使えるかもしれません。

```
CREATE TABLE triangle (
  sidea DOUBLE,
  sideb DOUBLE,
  sidec DOUBLE AS (SQRT(sidea * sidea + sideb * sideb))
);
INSERT INTO triangle (sidea, sideb) VALUES(1,1),(3,4),(6,8);

mysql> SELECT * FROM triangle;
+-------+-------+--------------------+
| sidea | sideb | sidec              |
+-------+-------+--------------------+
|     1 |     1 | 1.4142135623730951 |
|     3 |     4 |                  5 |
|     6 |     8 |                 10 |
+-------+-------+--------------------+
```

参考
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: itmammoth様、ご指導頂きまして感謝いたします。バージョンは4.6.6ですが、今後の参考にさせて頂きます。ありがとうございます。